# How to keep same texture coordinates on model exported from Blender to glTF?

Tags: texture-coordinates, gltf

How can I keep the texture looking same as in Blender? In the GLTF viewer it always looks like there is no "texture coordinate" node connected. When I connect this node, the texture changes in Blender, but it does not change in the GLTF exported file. It still looks the same no matter what kind of connection of texture coordinate node I use (Generated, Normal, Object...). It all looks the same in GLTF, as if the texture coordinate node were not connected at all.

How can I fix this?

Here is how it looks in Blender:
[image]

And this is how it looks in GLTF viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The glTF format needs an actual UV map, not Blender-generated coordinates.  Blender offers many ways to bake or project different kinds of coordinates into a UV map, many of which are available with the <kbd>u</kbd> shortcut when in "Edit Mode."

Blender's glTF exporter also [supports UV transformations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#uv-mapping) to a limited extent.  You should avoid complex things like nonuniform-scale rotations of UV coordinates, but a simple transform will work.

Ultimately you'll need to get your coordinates into a UV Map and assign that to the material, before exporting to glTF.

Comment: To mimic generated coordinates select top view and press U in edit mode and click Project From View and then you might want to move the uv island around a bit if you want it to be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well, the thing is uv mapping will take too much time and i have to do this to nearly thousand of different objects.

Worse thing is i dont know how to create same effect of the node below without that.

[image: reflection texture coordinates]

Comment: Stack Exchange prefers that you don't add new questions in the answer section.  You should edit your answer so it answers the question the OP asked, or you should delete it and add a comment or even a new question of your own.